# updating ActiveX checkbox in word using openxml

Tags: c#

Can any one tell me how to Edit an ActiveX checkbox in a word document using c#.

I have used the below code to enumerate through checkboxes in word, but don't know how to check or uncheck those checkbox.

```
OpenXmlPart part = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartById(ctrl.Id);

OpenXmlReader re = OpenXmlReader.Create(part.GetStream());

re.Read();

OpenXmlElement el = re.LoadCurrentElement();          

if(el.GetAttribute("classid", el.NamespaceUri).Value == "{8BD21D40-EC42-11CE-    9E0D-00AA006002F3}")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Checkbox found...");
}

re.Close();
```

Thanks in Advance